# Trouble using width for String in for-in cycle

Tags: swift, for-loop, for-in-loop

I've write a simple code:

```
extension String {
    func trailingSpaces (width: Int) -> String {
        var s = "\(self)"
        for i in count(s)..<width {
            s = s + " "
        }
        return s
    }

    func leadingSpaces (width: Int) -> String {
        var s = "\(self)"
        for i in count(s)..<width {
            s = " " + s
        }
        return s
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var users = ["Marco", "Gianni", "Antonio", "Giulio", "Franco"]
    var ages = [29, 45, 17, 33, 37]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var merged = [String: Int] ()
        var totalAge = 0.0

        for var i = 0; i < ages.count; i++ {
            merged[users[i]] = ages[i]
        }

        for user in sorted(merged.keys) {
            let age = merged[user]
            totalAge += Double(age!)
            let paddedUser = user.trailingSpaces(10)
            let paddedAge = "\(age)".leadingSpaces(3)
            println("\(paddedUser) \(age!)")
        }

        println("\n\(merged.count) users")
        println("average age: \(totalAge / Double(merged.count))")
    }
}
```

but I can't make it work the leadingSpaces function and I can't understand the reason, it's quite identical to the other extension func that works.

It give the error

> fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start

on runtime

Comment: are you using an int for width that is smaller than the value of count(s)? the error states that you want to iterate between a value and a smaller value. Swift can only iterate “upwards” in a default for loop

Comment: There's a correct answer to my question: I was passing a wrapped String, so string was "Optional(x)" instead of aspected "x" so width become smaller than count(s) and get crash!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you run into this kind of problem, always do a println() of the variable you are using

`println("\(age)")` right before `let paddedAge = "\(age!)".leadingSpaces(3)`
 reveals the problem

`age` is an optional, meaning that you are trying to do the padding on a `String` which has this value `"Optional(17)"`

Thus, your `count(s)` is higher than 3, and you have an invalid range

Comment: You're right! I've never thought that the Optional() word increase length of the String but it's true! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `age` is not an `Int` - it's an optional - `Int?`. You know this already as you are unwrapping it in the lines `totalAge += Double(age!)` and `println("\(paddedUser) \(age!)")` - but you are not unwrapping it in the failing line `let paddedAge = "\(age)".leadingSpaces(3)`. The string being passed to `leadingSpaces` is not "17", it's "Optional(17)", which is why your padding function is failing, as the length is greater than the requested width.

Having said that, as the commentator @milo256 points out, Swift can only iterate upwards, and so unless you put a check on width >= .count in your padding functions they will crash at some point.